# jQuery Ui Slider - Tooltip only showing on slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI slider on my page and want the tooltip to show at all times, not just when the user is sliding the handle.

How would I go about forcing to stay visible, I have tried appending a `display:block !important;` and `visibility: visible;` rule to the html element but this has not worked.

HTML

```
       <form id="pumpSlider" action="" method="GET" align="center">
          <div align="center" class="productSlider">
             <p class="inlineLabel">PSI</p><div class="filterSlider" id="psiSlider"></div>  
             <input id="pS" type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php echo $pVal ?>">
          </div>
       </form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var initialValueA = document.getElementById("pS").value;

    var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
        var curValue = ui.value || initialValueA;
        var target = ui.handle;                                     
        var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';
        $(target).html(tooltip);    
    }

    $("#psiSlider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value: initialValueA,
        min: -1,
        max: <?php echo $psiOut ?>,
        step: 1,
        create: sliderTooltip,
        slide: sliderTooltip
    });
});
```

This code creates the tooltip and sets its value to be used in the event code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#psiSlider" ).slider({
// options
start: function (event, ui) {

},
slide: function( event, ui ) {                     
    var curValue = ui.value || initialValueA;
    var target = ui.handle || $('.ui-slider-handle');                                     
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';
    $(target).html(tooltip);



    var valA = $('#psiSlider').slider("value");
    document.getElementById('pS').value = valA;   
    var valB = $('#gpmSlider').slider("value");
    document.getElementById('gS').value = valB;                   

},
change: function(event, ui) {
    var val = $('#pS').slider("value");
    var val = $('#gS').slider("value");
    $('#pumpSlider').submit();
}
});
```

What do I need to add in order to force the tooltip to always display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JQuery UI Manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-create) sais:

> **create( event, ui )**
>   
>   *Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events.*

That means you cannot access ui.value at creation. But you are able to access the value property nonetheless by the corresponding [getter](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-value).

```
$(function() {
      var showLabel = function(event,ui){
      var curValue = ui.value || $( this ).slider( "option", "value" );
            var target = ui.handle || $('.ui-slider-handle');                                     
            var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';
            $(target).html(tooltip);
      };
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:1,
      slide:showLabel,
      create:showLabel
      });
});
```

See [Proof of Concept JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pY3ZZ/2/)